# Run a task when the application is in background Ionic and Native Approach

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic application and one of the features involves taking down the notes in the app. The notes taking can be performed when the app is offline. The data is stored in the local storage.

Now, I want that when the customer comes online the data that is stored in the local storage (PouchDB) is pushed to the server. The problem is that the app might not be in the foreground. The app can be in suspended state. How can I wake the app up when the user comes online and then push the data to the server or perform any task?

I would be interested in hearing the Ionic approach and also native approach. Thanks

Comment: Is your problem has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with Data PushNotifications in IONIC...
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/